# Shutting down a LED when a script fails

Tags: gpio, python, python-3, led

I have a python3 script which is started by systemd automatically on boot. This script turns on a green LED to signal that the script has started.

Now I want the LED to turn off if the script **fails/crashes**. How would I go about doing this? I know how to turn off the LED in my code, but if the script crashes, nothing more executes to turn off my LED.

Do I need a secondary script with its own systemd service which monitors my main script and turns off the LED when the primary script crashes, or is there any better/cleaner solution to this problem?

Comment: What could cause your script to crash? Are you using try except to catch anything that could be an issue?

Comment: Well, like CoderMike said, you can just `try:` and `except (your exception that gets raised):`and then in the `except` part just turn the LED off.

Comment: sounds like you need a watchdog program to monitor the health of your main script ... have a shared data that the main script can update and the watchdog check for periodic updates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper script. When the python script crashes, the wrapper script can turn off the LED.

So, the wrapper script would be a simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash
your_pythonscript
echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```